# Replacing "." in a file unix

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I am attempting to replace any periods that occur in the middle of a string in a file.

I have tried `sed` using `'s/./5/g'` as well as `'s/'.'/5/g` and `'s/"."/5/g'` and none of them give me the output I want.

The first option replaces the whole file by a single 5, the second replaces every single character with a 5 and the third doesn't seem to do anything (I use grep to count occurrences of . and they are still there).

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated

Infile:

```
010001010.10101010101
```

outfile needed:

```
010001010510101010101
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexp pattern `.` means "any character". You want `s/\./5/g`

Comment: Or perhaps `s/[.]/5/g`; a bit more robust against extra unescaping passes (if the command is being passed through ssh or somewhere else where it gets munged before execution).

Comment: `echo 'a.b' | ssh localhost "sed 's/\./5/g'"` works just fine.

Comment: @ikegami, yes, quoting correctly like that, it will. Not everyone does correct quoting all the time. Consider `ssh localhost sed s/\./5/g` -- which fails in a way that `ssh localhost sed s/[.]/5/g` won't. (Failing to quote there is bad practice for other reasons, but again, the point is robustness for folks who don't follow good practices)

Comment: Of course, for global replacement of a single character, `echo "a.b" | tr . 5` may be more efficient, and for a  value in a variable, `echo "${var//./5}"`

Comment: @Charles Duffy, All the more reason to use `s/\./5/g`. Making bugs more visible is a good thing, especially since we're talking about command injection.

Comment: I still disagree with promoting a less-robust practice when a more-robust alternative is available, but have used the same reasoning myself in other discussions, so I have little room to talk. Be well.

Answer (score 0):

just add backslash before dot since it's special character

```
sed 's/\./5/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is with "." also being used as a wildcard. You can solve this by ESCAPING it with \ so it will be like `s/\./5/g`

Answer (score 0):

For a simple transformation you can use tr:

```
cat file | tr "." "5"
```